# AttributeRouting to Fix Two Params named Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

So I've got a project using the default `Route` of

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

I just ran into a situation described 7 years ago at [MVC Pro Tip: Don't use the "id" URL parameter in your routes](https://kamranicus.com/posts/2011-11-02-mvc-pro-tip-dont-use-the-id-url-parameter-in-your).

The solution they have is great and all, but at this moment, I do not want to change my entire site. I was hoping to fix my issue with [Attribute Routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

However, I cannot seem to get this to work, and I receive a `404 Error` page. (just in case the link above does not work, I'll describe the code in detail here).

**Details**

In my project I use `ViewModels`. The `ViewModel` is (very simply) defined as:

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My `BarController` is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Create(string id) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string id, Foo viewModel) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}
```

**Error**

When I navigate to `/Bar/Create/abc123`, I see my form just fine. However, when I submit the form, `Model.IsValid` is `false`. Looking at `Watch` window for the `this.ModelState` object, I found the error message to say

> The value 'abc123' is not valid for Id.'

I assume that's because the model binder is trying to bind `abc123` to `Id` on the `ViewModel` which has an `int` as the `Id` property.

**What I've Tried**

Here's what I've attempted to do so far on my `Controller`:

```
[Route("Bar/Create/{aid}", Name = "FooBarRouteName")]
public ActionResult Create(string aid) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aid)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string aid, Foo viewModel) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aid)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem now is when I navigate to `/Bar/Create/abc123`, I get a `404 Error` page and cannot even try to submit the form.

Can someone point me in the right direction or figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you consider renaming the `id` property in `Foo`?

Comment: I was, but I'd like to know how to make this work if I couldn't. =) I like to learn how to solve these things, not just "bandaid" them

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654273/two-fields-with-the-same-name help?

Comment: You are missing a route on the POST action. If using attribute routing you have to decorate all actions

Comment: @Nkosi thanks. I'll add it there too, if I end up going this route.

Comment: Not sure if related, what happens if you also use HttpGetAttribute?

Comment: @mjwills, so you're saying I should create a new `ViewModel` which contains a property of `Foo`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt, I can try it. Testing NKosi's solution first.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt same `404` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ensure that attribute routing is enabled before convention-based routes to avoid route conflicts.

```
//Attribute routing
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

//Convention-based routing
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

You are missing a route on the POST action.

If using attribute routing you have to decorate all actions on the controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Bar/Create/{aid}", Name = "FooBarRouteName")] // GET Bar/Create/abc123
public ActionResult Create(string aid) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aid)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("Bar/Create/{aid}")] // POST Bar/Create/abc123
public ActionResult Create(string aid, Foo viewModel) {
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aid)) {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Still cannot access initial page of `Bar/Create/abc123`

Comment: Thanks! I have enabled it, as I have it `AttributeRouting` on other controllers. I also have the `HttpGetAttribute` to. still same =/

Comment: This works! I didn't catch to caveat of `ensure that attribute routing is enabled before convention-based routes`

Answer (score 2):

Dump question: Did you updated your RegisterRoutes in the `RouteConfig`?

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // should be the first call
```

Also make sure, you are calling above before you are registering the default routes. That's because first configuration matches first, when the router is resolving the route.

Also you need to ensure you have the correct order in global.asax, in case you are using areas:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //needs to be first
AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

As [answered by Nkosi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51434334/2441442) you should also add the `RouteAttribute` to your other action and decorate your GET Action with the `HttpGetAttribute`.

Comment: Is that call above `routes.MapRoute`? @RoLYroLLs

Comment: That is your problem @RoLYroLLs

Comment: i just notice your solution more carefully. gonna try it.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs the order you add routes is important. Attribute routes need to be registered before convention based routes.

Comment: Wow! That worked! i'm going to test my other routes to make sure all is well.

Comment: Since @Nkosi answered first and I didn't "pay attention" to the "order is important" part, I'm going to give him the accepted answer. Thanks for your help!